# Using or and between together in Loopback restful api filter

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I am facing the problem of this.
If I want to apply this kind of filter in loopback restful api filter.

between(0,7) or between(11,17) or between(21,27)

How to write the filter script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code:

```
var myFilter = {
  where: {
        or: [{
            val: {
                between: [0, 7]
            }
        }, {
            val: {
                between: [11, 17]
            }
        }, {
            val: {
                between: [21, 27]
            }
        }]
    }
};

MyModel.find(myFilter, function (err, instances) {
  // Code to apply on found instances 
});
```

You can use [a stringified JSON](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-Using%22stringified%22JSONinRESTqueries) version of a filter in your REST queries.